# I'm trying to create a webpage using Python, Flask and php... The problem is it is showing these error: parameter 'primary_key' unfilled error

Tags: python, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

This my code I'm trying to create a webpage with the database but now it is showing errors and problems. How can I fix them?
This is the code of the main.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='template')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:@localhost/codingthunder'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Contacts(db.Model):
    sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    phone_num = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=False)
    msg = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20), Nullable=False)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')


@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contacts():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        '''Add entry to the database'''
        name = request.form.get('name')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        phone = request.form.get('phone')
        message = request.form.get('message')

        entry = Contacts(name=name, phome_num=phone, msg=message, email=email)
        db.session.add(entry)
        db.session.cummit()

    return render_template('contact.html')


app.run(debug=True)
```

Error and Problem:

[image: Error]
[image: Problem]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the email column from Nullable to nullable

`email = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)`